# Import a list of modules in a file in Python

Tags: python

I have a file named `imp.py`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

I also have another file named `test.py`, I want to import the modules in `imp.py`, therefore, I wrote

```
import imp.py
```

But the modules haven't been imported. What should be the correct approach?

Comment: Lose the `.py` extension: `import imp`.

Comment: In the beginning of 'test.py', I removed '.py' and it becomes 'import imp' now. However, it still gives the error of "NameError: name 'pd' is not defined"

Comment: I get the answer:

exec(open(r"imp.py", "r").read()